# When does $h(x^2+y^2)$ be harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Find all real-valued functions $h$, defined and of class $C^2$ on the positive real line, such that the function $u(x,y)=h(x^2 + y^2)$ is harmonic.

I was thinking that it will be harmonic only if $h$ will be constant.

**My attempt:**

Since $u$ is harmonic, $$ u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0 $$ 
$ u_{xx}=4x^2h_{xx}+2h_x $ and $u_{yy}=4y^2h_{yy}+2h_y$. So, 
$$ 4\Big(x^2h_{xx}+y^2 h_{yy}\Big)+2\Big( h_x+h_y \Big) =0$$

After that I stuck. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $h:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, what do "$h_x$" and "$h_y$" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ u=h(x^2+y^2) $
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{ \partial u} {\partial x} =2x h'(x^2+y^2) \\
\frac{ \partial^2 u} {\partial x^2} = 4x^2 h''(x^2+y^2)+ 2 h'(x^2+y^2).  \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Substitute this into $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ and let $z=x^2+y^2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\color{blue}{zh''(z)+h'(z)=0}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

For every $z>0$, $z=x^2+y^2$ describes a circle with center $(0,0)$. The mean value of $u(x,y)$ over this circle is $h(z)$, and this must be equal to $u(0,0)=h(0)$ due to the [mean value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) of harmonic functions.

Comment: This would be the answer if the question said non-negative real line rather than *positive* real line.