# Harmonic functions of the form $f(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm working on the following problem:

> Find all harmonic functions on $\mathbb R^2$ of the form $f(x^2+y^2)$, where $f$ is of class $C^2$.

What I've done so far: Define $u(x,y)=f(x^2+y^2)$. Then the second-order partial derivatives of $u$ are
$$
u_{xx}=2f'(x^2+y^2)+4x^2f''(x^2+y^2),\\
u_{yy}=2f'(x^2+y^2)+4y^2f''(x^2+y^2).
$$
If $u$ is harmonic then $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, so we have
$$
f'(x^2+y^2)+(x^2+y^2)f''(x^2+y^2)=0.
$$
At this point I'm not quite sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well $f’$ is a solution of the ODE $y+xy’=0$, so can you go on?

Comment: The condition in that older questions are slightly different, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422636/42969) fits exactly your problem. It shows why a radially symmetric  harmonic function defined in the *entire plane* is necessarily constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $r= x^2 +y^2$ then you get $$f'(r) +r f''(r) =0$$
and $$\frac{f''(r)}{f'(r)} dr = -\frac{1}{r} dr$$
hence $$\ln |f'(r)| =\ln|r| +C$$
and $$f'(r)= \frac{C}{r}$$ therefore $$f(r) =C\ln |r| +D$$

and hence $$u(x,y) =C\ln (x^2 +y^2 ) +D$$